# i want to share the channels variable in all the view but when i add the view::share method in the App service providers boot function

Tags: laravel

i want to share the channels variable in all the view but when i add the view::share method in the App service providers boot function it shows me the error of view class not found i am sharing the code and the error please help

```
 <?php

   namespace App\Providers;
   use view;
    use App\Channel;
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
     use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;


   class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
     {
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
      * @return void
 */
        public function boot()
        {
         view::share('channels',Channel::all()); 
          Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

          }
```

Comment: well the class is `View` not `view` but you know ...

Comment: yeah i got that

Comment: then your problem is solved ... yay